# How do I open a file txt in a specific folder using visual studio c++?

Tags: c++, ifstream

This is the part of code where I try to open the file f1.txt, it is complete path is C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\NSGA2-CDS\DataSet\f1.txt

`ifstream fichier("C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\NSGA2-CDS\DataSet\f1.txt", ios::in);`

The file cannot be opened and I don't know why?!

NSGA2-CDS is the folder that contain the visual studio solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape backslashes in the path string:

```
ifstream fichier("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\NSGA2-CDS\\DataSet\\f1.txt", ios::in);
```

This has nothing to do with file I/O as such; it's a feature of string literals: `\` is used to escape special characters (such as `\n`, `\t`), so when it appears in a string, it needs to be escaped as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use raw string literal so you don't need to escape individual char.

```cpp
ifstream fichier(R"(C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\NSGA2-CDS\DataSet\f1.txt)", ios::in);
```